# Какими методами лучше инициализировать параметры класса. (Лист инициализации, move семантика, вызов конструктора через конструктор)

Tags: c++, ооп

задался вопросом относительно того, что и когда правильнее использовать. Был бы благодарен если бы объяснили как работает нижеперечисленные фрагменты кода, которые я нашёл в просторах интернета и не слишком понимаю как они работают.

Предположим класс Node имеет два параметра Type value и Node *nextp.

Тут при создании объекта класса Node, вызывается конструктор класса, а передача значения происходит с помощью move семантики? В чём преимущество такой инициализации и какие у него недостатки?

```
 template<typename Type>
inline Node<Type>::Node(Type v) : value(v), nextp(nullptr)
{
}
```

Тут при создании объекта класса Node, вызывается конструктор класса, а передача значения происходит с помощью списка/листа инициализации? Происходит ли инициализация параметров класса в динамической памяти (в heap) или же параметры остаются статичными? Как добиться в этом случае инициализации параметров в динамическую паять?

```
template<typename Type>
inline Node<Type>::Node(Type v) : value{v}, nextp{nullptr}
{
}
```

Таким же образом через конструктор Node наверное пытались вызывать некий другой конструктор, который вызывал бы инициализацию поля/параметра value. Является ли такой способ правильным?

```
template<typename Type>
inline Node<Type>::Node(Type v) : anc_constructor(v), nextp(nullptr)
{
}
```

Comment: `: ...` — список инициализации, `std::move` — вызов перемещающих конструкторов при наличии, `Node(...)` — делегация инициализации другому конструктору. См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor и https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, комментатору выше. Окончательный ответ был бы невозможным без него.
Так вот. Как оказалось существенной разницы между () и {} скобкам в списке инициализаторов нет. Их единственное отличие в том, что при инициализации значений через {} скобки не происходит преобразования типа.

В то же время, попытки вызова конструктора предка невозможно целом (если не инициализировать или динамически выделять память для объекта класса предка в списке инициализаторов). Поэтому вышеперечисленные код или является ошибкой или нечто иным, чем просто вызов конструктора.

Comment: "Как оказалось существенной разницы между () и {} скобкам в списке инициализаторов нет." ну как нет, попробуйте проинициализировать `std::vector<int>` одним и другим способом. Обнаружите большую разницу.

Comment: В ответе имелось ввиду про эти скобки в списках инициализаторах. А вот насчёт вектора попробую, спасибо!

Comment: Я понял, где имелось в виду. Вот и попробуйте сделать мембером `std::vector<int>` и инициализуруйте его к примеру `{ 10 }`, а затем `( 10 )` и ощутите разницу.